# I can't return List<bean> from the Json? Java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, json, spring

There is json in my metod. I want json change to object bean. compiler warns and asks to remove generic.

This example does not work:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<MyBean> myBean = gson.fromJson(
            result.getBody(), List<myBean>.class);
```

So does run, but I can not get to the bean:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<MyBean> myBean = gson.fromJson(
            result.getBody(), List.class);
MyBean.get(0).getFirstName();
```

error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to com.home.bean.MyBean

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: So where does categoryNameBean come from then? and how is it declared?

Comment: I am sorry. I wanted to write MyBean

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   Type myBeanListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyBean>>() {}.getType();
   List<MyBean> mappedList = new Gson().fromJson(result.getBody(), myBeanListType );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would have to be changed to:

```
List<MyBean> myBean = gson.fromJson(result.getBody(), new TypeToken<List<MyBean>>() {}.getType());
```

Per the Gson user guide [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), (under ***Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types*** section):

> When you call toJson(obj), Gson calls obj.getClass() to get
>   information on the fields to serialize. Similarly, you can typically
>   pass MyClass.class object in the fromJson(json, MyClass.class) method.
>   This works fine if the object is a non-generic type. However, if the
>   object is of a generic type, then the Generic type information is lost
>   because of Java Type Erasure.
>
> You can solve this problem by specifying the correct parameterized
>   type for your generic type. You can do this by using the TypeToken
>   class.

Hence, you would have to use `TypeToken` when dealing with generics.